# Java Code Build Error in Visual Studio Code: Debugger for Java (Extension)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to run a Java program in [tag: Visual Studio Code], and I'm encountering a build error with the following message:

```
Build failed, do you want to continue? Source: Debugger for Java (Extension).
```

I'm using the following Java extensions in Visual Studio Code:

- Extension Pack for Java v0.25.14 Microsoft
- Debugger for Java v0.54.2023092623 Microsoft
- Test Runner for Java v0.40.0 Microsoft
- Project Manager for Java v0.23.1 Microsoft
- Maven for Java v0.42.0 Microsoft
- Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat v1.23.0
- Java Debugger v0.1.5 Don Jayamanne
- Java Run v1.1.4 caolin

Here's my Java code:

```java
class Solution {
    // 605. Can Place Flowers LeetCode
    // Day2 5 Oct 2022
    
    public boolean canPlaceFlowers(int[] flowerbed, int n){

        int zeros = 1, ans = 0;
        for (itn i = 0; i < flowerbed.length; i ++) {
            if (flowerbed[i] == 0){
                ++zeros;
            } else{
                ans += (zero -1) / 2;
                zeros = 0;
            }//ifelse
        }//for loop
        return ans + zeros / 2 >= n;
    }//canPlaceFlowers

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        canPlaceFlowers output = new canPlaceFlowers();
        int[] inputArray = {1,0,0,0,1};
        int n = 1;
        boolean answer = output.canPlaceFlowers(inputArray, n);

        System.out.println(answer);
    }

}//class
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, and I'd like to understand what's causing it and how to resolve it.

I'm trying to solve a LeetCode problem and learning debugging in Java at the same time :( Additionally, I'd appreciate it if someone could confirm whether I have the correct extensions and debuggers installed for Java development in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: What if you disable `Java Debugger v0.1.5 Don Jayamanne` and `Java Run v1.1.4 caolin`?

Comment: how exactly are you invoking build? is there any relevant build configuration info you're not showing us yet? Is there any more info anywhere (including the Output Panel) about the build failure?

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that the [complete Java extension package](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) is installed and use the Java extension to execute the program.

At the same time, you can use the `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace` command to clean and restart vscode. Or [completely uninstall vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall#_clean-uninstall) and start again.

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial